# nativescript how to make element transparent to touch events

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, telerik, nativescript

For one of my projects, I need to develop a vignetting effect over a google map in nativescript (IOS App) so I decided to go with the png24 image solution stretching over the google map view.

```
<GridLayout id="appContainer">
        <MapView id="mapView"></MapView>
        <Image src="~/images/vignettage.png" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></Image>
</GridLayout>
```

Now obviously I run into a problem when trying to interact with the map, the touch gestures, pan gestures and so are taken over by the overlaying image.

How can I make this image transparent to touch events, in the same way the css `pointer-events:none;` does in websites for cursor events.

Any typescript.javascript or pure objective-c solution welcome!

Just added an image to illustrate this issue : 
[image]

Comment: Are you hooking to any events on the image with: image.on('pan', ()) etc? If not, the events should be passing through. At least on android it's working if I don't listen to image events.

Comment: Can you try putting `ios:isUserInteractionEnabled="false"` on the image component?

Comment: @VictorNascimento That works! Tried to add this in code with nativeElement but didn't worked. puttin it in the template works! thanks a lot, please post it as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's related on how iOS and Android treat event bubbling. For iOS you should put 
`ios:isUserInteractionEnabled="false"` on the overlay template to let events pass through.

Comment: Just in case you know how to do it for android, don't hesitate to add it in the response. Thank you

Comment: On Android you actually don't need to do anything.